# Is my return value actually being returned?

Tags: java

When I compile this code, it gives me an error that says it "cannot find symbol" for the variable count. Am I not returning it correctly? Or do I have to declare the variable in the main method, and not in the wordScore method?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
public class assignment3 {
public static void main (String []args){
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  double totalCount = 0;
  //ask user to enter a movie review line
  System.out.println("Please enter a one line movie review ");
  String oneLineMovieReview = input.nextLine();

  //putting each word into a string array
  String[] words = oneLineMovieReview.split(" ");

  //calling the wordScore method to calculate word score for each word
  for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
     wordScore(words[i]);
     totalCount = totalCount + count;
  }                
}
public static double wordScore(String oneLineMovieReview) {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  double count = 0;
  double sumScore = 0;
  double average = 0;
  int totalCount = 0;


  File file = new File("movieReviews.txt");

  try {

     Scanner fInput = new Scanner(file);
     while (fInput.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = fInput.nextLine();
        if (line.contains(oneLineMovieReview)){
           count++;
           sumScore += Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0,1));
        } 
     }

    System.out.println("The word " + oneLineMovieReview + " appears " + 
count + " times.");
    average = sumScore / count;
    System.out.println("The average score is " + average);
    System.out.println(totalCount);
    System.out.println();
  } catch(Exception e) { }

  return count;      

  }
}
```

Comment: The declaration of `count` is not visible to the `main` method and you never assign the return value of `wordScore()` to anything.  You need to perhaps do `totalCount = totalCount + wordScore(words[i])`  (or even just `double count = wordScore(words[i])`)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here, you do

```
for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
   wordScore(words[i]);
   totalCount = totalCount + count;
}
```

Now, `count` isn't visible here as it was declared in the `wordScore` method. I suppose you intended doing

```
for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
   totalCount = totalCount + wordScore(words[i]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Both `main` and `woreScore` are static methods, meaning they share no state except for members of the class which are also `static`. The `main` method needs its own `count` variable, keeping in mind this will be separate from the one in any other function. For `main` and `wordScore` to share the same value of `count`, the variable will have to either be `static`, or the functions extracted into a separate class and made non-static.

(Also, it's often best to keep the class which has the `main` entry point separate from the class doing your program's actual work).